# publishing a poster in a conference and then an extended version in another conference, is that possible?

Tags: conference, poster

I was planning to submit a couple of posters to a Computer Science conference because there are some final experiments that I should perform with the data we have at hand. I wondered if there would be an issue if I submit the complete work to another conference and citing the first conference in which I present the work as a poster, would there be some issues regarding the level of novelty required for a conference. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as you cite the earlier work, you can submit it without issue. But it is up to the conference committee to decide if the "complete work" is sufficiently novel, given that the earlier version already exists. For many such things it would be fine, but no one but the committee can say anything about acceptance.

But, with proper citation, there are no ethical issues such as self plagiarism.

But you should also consider copyright if you have given it up. If so, this limits how extensively you can copy from the earlier work into the new and you may be restricted to quoting (literally) brief passages or paraphrasing (with citation).

The more extensive the changes are, the more likely that you will have success. Just make sure it ins't perceived as "old news".

---

Note that there may be overlap in the conference committees.

Answer (score 0):

In the field of natural language processing (NLP), the main conferences explicitly state the maximum overlap requirements between the paper submissions and past published work, [e.g.](https://2021.aclweb.org/calls/papers/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210628021159/https://2021.aclweb.org/calls/papers/)):

> In addition, we will not consider any paper that overlaps significantly in content or results with papers that will be (or have been) published elsewhere. Authors submitting more than one paper to ACL-IJCNLP 2021 **must ensure that submissions do not overlap significantly (>25%) with each other in content or results**.